# Locking a thread function using Monitor::Enter Monitor::Exit

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I have a thread class with two functions:

```
using namespace System::Threading;
public ref class SecThr
{
public:
 int j;

void wralot()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=400000;i++)
    {
    j=i;
    if ((i%10000)==0) 
        Console::WriteLine(j);
    }
}

void setalot()
{
    Monitor::Enter(this);
    for (int i=0; i<=400000;i++)
    {
    j=7;
    }
    Monitor::Exit(this);

}
 };


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
Console::WriteLine("Hello!");

SecThr^ thrcl=gcnew SecThr;
Thread^ o1=gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(thrcl, &SecThr::wralot));
Thread^ o2=gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(thrcl, &SecThr::setalot));
o2->Start();
o1->Start();
o1->Join();
o2->Join();
```

So, for locking "setalot" function i've used MOnitor::Enter-Exit block. But the output is like i'm running only one thread with function "wralot"

0
10000
20000
30000
40000
7 //here's "setalot" func
60000
e t.c.

Why all the output data is not changed to const (7) by "setalot" func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `Monitor::Enter` does. It's only a cooperative lock - and as `wralot` doesn't try to obtain the lock at all, the actions of `setalot` don't affect it. It's not really clear why you expected to get a constant output of 7 due to `setalot` - if `wralot` *did* try to obtain the lock, it would just mean that one of them would "win" and the other would have to wait. If `wralot` had to wait, there'd be no output while `setalot` was running, and then `wralot` would go do its thing - including setting `j` to `i` on every iteration.

So basically, both threads are starting, and `setalot` *very quickly* sets `j` to `7` a lot of times... that's likely to complete in the twinkling of an eye in computer terms, compared with a `Console.WriteLine` call. I suggest you add a call to `Console::WriteLine` at the end of `setalot` so you can see when it's finished. Obviously after that, it's completely irrelevant - which is why you're seeing 60000, 70000 etc.